# Console and file appender is working but date based logging not working when using slf4j

Tags: java, slf4j

First come to the problem. I can see logs in console and file but I want to create a log file each day and do logging on it. But I am unable despite I have mentioned in my logging configuration file for this.
Following is my logback.xml;

```
<configuration>

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>app.log</file>
    <append>true</append>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd} %X{akkaTimestamp} %-5level[%thread] %logger{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <!--<pattern>%X{akkaTimestamp} %-5level[%thread] %logger{0} - %msg%n</pattern>-->
        <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd} %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level[%thread] %logger{0} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>


<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>
```

Following is the java code to do some logging;

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NetworkServer.class);
```

log.info("doing logging");

Any help will be appreciated in this regard. Do let me know if there is something else required as well to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

The settings look okay.

Note that by setting the `file` property as well, the current file will be named `app.log` (without any extension). But if you keep this running until the next day, that one should be archived away (and get the datestamp in the process), and a new log be started as `app.log`. Or you could remove the `file` setting to have the active log be timestamped as well (that also avoids potential problems when renaming during rollover).

Comment: Thanks for reply @Thilo. But I believe that this line shall create new file each day named as something like logFile.2016-02-20.log; <fileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>.......Don't you think?

Comment: It should create these files by moving "yesterday's" app.log away (if there is one). Doesn't it?

Comment: You may have to let it run over night to see that.

Comment: Let me do this....but I must tell you server has kept running for more than a day and  new files were not created....Though I did not delete log.file....I doubt it would work but still I try this out.